# Symlink in crontab, script not found

Tags: php, cron, symlink

I'm running Debian testing and can't get a simple cron to run a symlinked PHP script.

I've a php script in a subdirectory in my home folder `/home/foobar/dir/script.php` (which starts with the following shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php`).

I've created a symlink which points to it:

```
sudo ln -s ~/dir/script.php /usr/local/bin/whatever
ls -la /usr/local/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 24 Feb 27 17:46 whatever -> /home/foobar/dir/script.php*
```

And added the following rule to my crontab (execute `whatever` every minute):

```
crontab -e
* * * * * whatever
```

But **it doesn't work**, I get the following error:

```
cat /var/mail/foobar
...
/bin/sh: 1: whatever: not found
```

While **pointing to the script without using the symlink works**:

```
crontab -e
* * * * * /home/foobar/dir/script.php
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Directories like `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` are not by default in cronjobs `$PATH`. But you can redefine `$PATH` in crontab, simply put something like this before any defined cronjobs

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Answer (score 0):

The $PATH environment variable under cron is limited, and will include neither /usr/local/bin nor /home/foobar/dir.  The correct answer is, as you found, to fully qualify the path to the script in your crontab; it leads to less surprises.